# How to change the subscription period start date in stripe while creating or updating subscription

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-5.4

I have integrated stripe in to my application. I want to create new subscription with custom subscription start date in stripe.
 Eg If plan is monthly then while creating subscription i want to pass subscription startdate to the stripe and stripe will create subscription for a month from that date.

So is it possible to do? Or stripe will create new subscription from the current date only?

I have used laravel cashier..

Subscription table

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->string('name');
$table->string('stripe_id');
$table->string('stripe_plan');
$table->integer('quantity');
$table->timestamp('trial_ends_at')->nullable();
$table->timestamp('ends_at')->nullable();
$table->timestamps();
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add detail of tables structure ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Trials](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/trials) for this.  Here are the [Cashier docs for Subscription Trials](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing#subscription-trials) as well.

Comment: In my application there is one another payment integration and as per flow if one user have already subscribed to the application via that payment and then if he uses stripe then it should create new subscription from first subscription end date.

Comment: That makes sense to me, ya.